# Highcharts yAxis title click

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I want to set the `yAxis` extremes on the `yAxis` title click.

```
yAxes[i].setExtremes(min, max);
```

I am able to capture the `onclick` event on the `yAxis` labels*. 
[Here is the JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rishad/dt9jwek4/)
but I want to enable click on `yAxis` title and get the values from the user and set extremes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To capture `onclick` for the axis title you can use your existing approach of iterating over the axis and adding a similar `onclick` function to the `axis.axisTitle.element` ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dt9jwek4/14/)):

```
var yAxes = pChart.yAxis;
yAxes.forEach(function(axis) {
    axis.labelGroup.element.childNodes.forEach(function(label){
        label.style.cursor = "pointer";
        label.onclick = function(){console.log('You clicked on '+this.textContent);};
    });
    axis.axisTitle.element.style.cursor = "pointer";
    axis.axisTitle.element.onclick = function(){console.log('You clicked on '+this.textContent);};
});
```

Comment: Thank you, thats what I needed +1